# Data Validation changing another Data Validation cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In the example sheet below. On Sheet 2 When the drop-down under "Client Remarks" changes to "Finalized By Client" I need Sheet 1 "Course Status" to change to "Finalized By Client". I tried this array formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Courses | Client Review'!A4 ="Finalized By Client","Finalized By Client",))
```

but I lose the drop-down menu and I need that to be there. Any help would be appreciated.

Example Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GqCv9vgzLYDKg9VcaJn9__8789N9rABH49-9CozGUHU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in **U2** cell:

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2, {Sheet2!B:B, Sheet2!A:A}, 2, 0))="Finalized By Client", 
 "Finalized By Client", {"In Queue", "In Progress", "Internal QA", "Client Review"})
```

[image: 0]

and set data validation on cell **B2** to:

[image: 0]

and then just hide those helper columns:

[image]